# MYSQL retrieve data dependent on rows returned

Tags: mysql, case-expression

I am working on a mysql query that will filter out certain occurrences dependent on how many rows are returned.

I am trying to filter out any support categories when the number of rows returned are 1, however leave the support category in when the result set turned is more than 1.

I originally had this idea however it seems as if it will not work.

```
SELECT stockmaster.description, SUM(salesorderdetails.quantity), stockmaster.categoryid         as qty 
FROM salesorderdetails, stockmaster 
where salesorderdetails.stkcode=stockmaster.stockid 
and orderno='5222'
group by stockmaster.description
HAVING CASE WHEN stockmaster.categoryid = 'S&M' THEN COUNT(*) >= 2 ELSE COUNT(*) = 1   END
```

Any help will be gratefully accepted.

Comment: provide some simple data by http://sqlfiddle.com/ and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

SELECT stockmaster.description, 
       SUM(salesorderdetails.quantity), 
       stockmaster.categoryid         as qty ,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM salesorderdetails, stockmaster 
where salesorderdetails.stkcode=stockmaster.stockid 
and orderno='5222'
group by stockmaster.description
HAVING CASE WHEN stockmaster.categoryid = 'S&M' 

) MAIN_DATA

WHERE MAIN_DATA.count >1
```